# Changing various columns depending on multiple other columns - R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm trying to find a convenient way to change value in a column, based on conditionals in other columns, so that when there's an NA and the conditionals are met, it will replace the value. I have about 6 columns, which are like A:D, and then one binary column. There's also other data related to these specific rows, eg(date, location etc.)

I've made some dummy code below

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
ops <- c("Zoo", "Fun", "Party")

df <- data.frame(A = c("Zoo", "Beer", "Rave", "Fun", "school"),
                 B = c("school", NA, "Beer", "exams", "Beer"),
                 C = c("Fun", NA, NA, "Party", "Rave"),
                 D = c(NA, NA, NA, "Rave", NA), 
                 X = c(1,0,1,0,0))

df$B[which((df$A %notin% ops | df$B %notin% ops |
                           df$C %notin% ops) & df$X == 0 & is.na(df$B))] <- "HELP"
df$C[which((df$A %notin% ops & df$B %notin% ops &
                           df$C %notin% ops) & df$X == 0 & 
                          df$B != "HELP" & is.na(df$C))] <- "HELP"
df$D[which((df$A %notin% ops & df$B %notin% ops &
                           df$C %notin% ops) & df$X == 0 & 
                          df$B != "HELP" & df$C != "HELP" &
                          is.na(df$D))] <- "HELP"
```

As you can see, this code is incrementally more confusing and challenging to follow. It's kind of incrementally grown this way as I've found new problems... I know there has to be a cleaner way of writing this, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I'm pretty familiar with the tidyverse(ish) - more so not looking for a data.table solution... But base R solutions would also be a godsend.

I have several other blocks of coding with conditionals like this at the moment (which is why having a solution that actually works would just be a huge jump in cleaning up this code).

EDIT: In request for an explanation of what I'm trying to do, let me explain a bit more clearly.

I want a more elegant solution for when I want to change a row value if it meets certain conditions. Here, each row is, let's say a categorial survey response, where `ops` contains the 3 categorical variables I'm interested in. X is a dummy variable (really just boolean).

For ease (and to not confuse the answer below, I'll change the df slightly.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("Zoo", "Beer", "Rave", "Fun", "school", "blah"),
                 B = c("school", NA, "Beer", "exams", "Beer", "blah"),
                 C = c("Fun", NA, NA, "Party", "Rave", NA),
                 D = c(NA, NA, NA, "Rave", NA, NA), 
                 X = c(1,0,1,0,0,1))
```

*The goal is to change the first NA iff the row doesn't contain ops & X==0*

But, I also do not want to change ALL NA's - I only want to change the first NA if it meets the condition (ie. row contains ops & X == 0) & I do not know *where* the 1st NA will appear in the data, but I do know after the 1st NA that if there are more columns the rest will be NA until X.

**If we take row 5:**

ops is not in A, B, C, D & X == 0 & is.na(D) therefore [5,5] == "HELP"

**If we take row 2:**

ops is not in A, B, C,D & B is.na & C is.na, and D is.na & X==0 BUT I only want to change the first appearance of NA

**The new row added (6)**

ops is not in A, B, C,D BUT X == 0. In this case, I still want "HELP" to occur where the first NA is.

I don't know if I made that more confusing - sorry not a computer scientist, but that's basically the logic structure I'm trying to achieve without having to change every row. I have 2 do this 2 more times with different versions of "HELP", based on different conditions, which then preclude the word HELP... So it's starting to get hard to parse.

Comment: Well done for providing your coding attempt but it would be helpful if you took a step back and just explained what you are trying to do.  It seems that when the binary column is `0` and the row doesn't contain any of the words in `ops`, you want to replace the first rowwise `NA` with `HELP`.  Is that it?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm working with confidential data (for the time being) - so I tried to provide a dummy data that was a bit playful. ^The code above actually works for what I need it to do - it's just messy and hard to work with.

Comment: @27ϕ9 I have added a more in depth explanation, but yes that's basically it. My issue is that after this I have to do this again and then write != "HELP" as well... Maybe it just needs to be messy, but there must be an easier way to replace the 1st rowise when condition A, B & C are met

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R you can do this in a scalable way by creating a matrix of row and column indices to change (as you tagged this question with tidyverse note this type of replacement won't work with tibbles):

```
# Create column index of first NA value
ci <- seq_along(df)[max.col(cbind(is.na(df), TRUE), ties.method = "first")]
# Create logical index of the rows that meet the conditions
ri <- rowSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, ops)) == 0 & df$X == 0
# Replace values using the indices
df[na.omit(cbind(which(ri), ci[ri]))] <- "HELP"
df

       A      B    C    D X
1    Zoo school  Fun <NA> 1
2   Beer   HELP <NA> <NA> 0
3   Rave   Beer <NA> <NA> 1
4   Rave  exams Beer Rave 0
5 school   Beer Rave HELP 0
```

**Edit:**

If it's necessary to work around other columns, you just need to use an indexed data frame instead of the entirety. For example:

```
# Create additional columns
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, df[1:3], month = month.abb[1:5], df[4:5])
```

So that the data frame now looks like:

```
  id      A      B     C month    D X
1  1    Zoo school   Fun   Jan <NA> 1
2  2   Beer   <NA>  <NA>   Feb <NA> 0
3  3   Rave   Beer  <NA>   Mar <NA> 1
4  4    Fun  exams Party   Apr Rave 0
5  5 school   Beer  Rave   May <NA> 0
```

You can index by position, but it's generally safer to index by name.  Note we can keep column `X` out of it for now as we only need to use it once and can use it directly:

```
colidx <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Then wherever the entire data frame was referenced in the original code, just replace it with the indexed data frame:

```
ci <- seq_along(df[colidx])[max.col(cbind(is.na(df[colidx]), TRUE), ties.method = "first")]
ri <- rowSums(sapply(df[colidx], `%in%`, ops)) == 0 &  df$X == 0
df[colidx][na.omit(cbind(which(ri), ci[ri]))] <- "HELP"
df
  id      A      B     C month    D X
1  1    Zoo school   Fun   Jan <NA> 1
2  2   Beer   HELP  <NA>   Feb <NA> 0
3  3   Rave   Beer  <NA>   Mar <NA> 1
4  4    Fun  exams Party   Apr Rave 0
5  5 school   Beer  Rave   May HELP 0
```

Comment: Can you walk me through this solution. Trying to figure out how to apply it to my real data. As noted above, the df has a few other variables columns in it (eg. date, location). I'm wondering how to pull this back together. I have an ID column, but I'm unsure how I'd match them back in if that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly more concise and in my opinion, easier to read solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(B = case_when((!A %in% ops | !B %in% ops | !C %in% ops) & X == 0 & is.na(B) ~ "HELP",
                       TRUE ~ B),
         C = case_when((!A %in% ops | !B %in% ops | !C %in% ops) & X == 0 & B != "HELP" & is.na(C) ~ "HELP",
                       TRUE ~ C),
         D = case_when(!A %in% ops & !B %in% ops & !C %in% ops & X == 0 & B != "HELP" & C != "HELP" & is.na(D) ~ "HELP",
                       TRUE ~ D))
```

This gives us:

```
    A      B     C    D X
1    Zoo school   Fun <NA> 1
2   Beer   HELP  <NA> <NA> 0
3   Rave   Beer  <NA> <NA> 1
4    Fun  exams Party Rave 0
5 school   Beer  Rave HELP 0
```

Note that `df %>% mutate(!variable %in% vector)` can be used as a replacement for `%notin%` `<- Negate(`%in%`)`

Comment: It's easier to read - but this is only going to get messier when I have to do my other variables. Do you think it's possible for a solution that is iterative instead, or maybe this is just not feasible. I also prefer using %notin% because I can set it as a function at the beginnning of the code and forget it, but that's preference

Comment: If I don't get another response, I will 100% mark this as a check. But I'm going to leave it open now with the hopes I can get something a bit more elegant